# Simple proof of an isomorphism theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I haven't references about a proof of this theorem:
Let $p: Y \rightarrow X$ be a fiber bundle. If for all $x \in X$ $p^{-1}(x)$ satisfies $H^{\ast}(p^{-1}(x)) \simeq \mathbb{R} $, then $p$ induces an isomorphism $ H^{\ast}(X) \simeq H^{*}(Y)$.
How could I prove this theorem? A spectral sequences argument for the fiber bundle?

Comment: Sure just write down the Serre spectral sequence and it's clear. There is the more classical Leray-Hirsch theorem as well that can work for this situation.

Comment: How could I write Serre spectral sequence here? 

Comment: The $E_2$-page just consists of a single horizontal line -- the homology of $Y$; i.e. there are no further differentials or filtrations, and you can read the homology of $X$ off directly from this line.

Comment: I haven't know how can I build the page $E_{2}$ and why there is only a horizontal line. What are $E_{1}$ and $E_{0}$ pages?